# Make 'uniq' return different array based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models: Camps, Coaches, and Countries. Camps has a Country and Coaches has a Country as well.

Something like this:

Camp Super Fun (Country: Denmark) and 
Camp No Fun (Country: England)

Coach Foo (Country: Italy) and 
Coach Bar (Country: Germany)

I have a simple search where users can filter Camps and Coaches based on country. When users filter through Camps I only want the Camps countries to appear in the dropdown (Denmark and England). When users filter through Coaches I want the Coach countries to appear in the dropdown (Italy and Germany).

How do I make the coach filter only have Coach Countries options and the camps filter only have Camps Countries?

Right now, I just get a list of all countries in both filters. Here are my models and controllers:

Camp.rb:

```
class Camp < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
  dragonfly_accessor :image
  def self.search(price, country, coach, start_date, end_date, city, language)

    camps = Camp.where("1 = 1")

    camps = camps.where("price <= ?", price) unless price == nil
    camps = camps.where("start_date >= ?", start_date) unless start_date == nil
    camps = camps.where("end_date <= ?", end_date) unless end_date == nil
    camps = camps.where("city LIKE ?", city) unless city == nil

    if country.present?
      camps = camps.joins(:countries).where(countries: { name: country })
    end

    if coach.present?
      camps = camps.joins(:coaches).where(coaches: { name: coach })
    end

    if language.present?
      camps = camps.joins(coaches: :languages).where(languages: { language_code: language })
    end

    camps
  end

  def languages
    coaches.flat_map { |coach| coach.languages.map(&:name)}
  end
end
```

Coach.rb:

```
class Coach < ApplicationRecord
  dragonfly_accessor :image
  has_and_belongs_to_many :camps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :athletes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries

  def self.search(country, city)

    coaches = Coach.where("1 = 1")

    if country.present?
      coaches = coaches.joins(:countries).where(countries: { name: country })
    end

    coaches = coaches.where("city LIKE ?", city) unless city == nil

    coaches
  end
end
```

Country.rb:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :camps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
end
```

coaches_controller.rb:

```
class CoachesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @featured_coaches = Coach.where(featured: true)
  end

  def search
    @coach_country = Country.uniq
    @coach_city = Coach.uniq.pluck(:city)

    country = params[:country].present? ? params[:country] : nil
    city = params[:city].present? ? params[:city] : nil

    @coaches = Coach.search(country, city)
  end

end
```

camps_controller.rb

```
class CampsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @featured_camps = Camp.where(featured: true)
    @camps_on_map = Camp.where(show_on_maps: true)
    @camp_count = Camp.count.to_s
  end

  def search
    @camp_coach = Coach.all.pluck(:name)
    @camp_country = Country.uniq
    @camp_city = Camp.uniq.pluck(:city)
    @camps = Camp.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @camp_language = Language.uniq

    price = params[:price].present? ? params[:price] : nil
    country = params[:country].present? ? params[:country] : nil
    coach = params[:coach].present? ? params[:coach] : nil
    start_date = params[:start_date].present? ? params[:start_date] : nil
    end_date = params[:end_date].present? ? params[:end_date] : nil
    city = params[:city].present? ? params[:city] : nil
    language = params[:language].present? ? params[:language] : nil

    @camps = Camp.search(price, country, coach, start_date, end_date, city, language)
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens to your code now? Is there an error?

Comment: And why call uniq on all your models (Countries, Cities, Languages)? Isn't it better to have unique validation so that you avoid duplicate in your models and your database?